# delete all the rows from DataTable after a condition in the first column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataTable` from where I need to delete rows of data after "`EOF`" data in the first column. For example,

```
CHECK_SUM | INPUT_CODE | TOKEN | SPEED
201865    | 56         | 1A    | 5
201866    | 48         | 1D    | 5
201867    | 87         | 2R    | 10
201868    | 45         | 2G    | 8
EOF
201869    | 99         | 0     | 0
201870    | 100        | 0     | 0
```

In this `DataTable`, after the value "EOF" I need to delete all the rows. How can I do that ?

Comment: find the datarow using `DataTable.Rows.Find` method get the index of the `EOF` row using `DataTable.Rows.IndexOf`, then use `DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt` in a loop to remove all rows greater than the index of `EOF`

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
           int? EOF = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((x, i) => new { row = x, index = i })
                .Where(x => x.row.Field<string>("CHECK_SUM") == "EOF")
                .Select(x => x.index)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if(EOF != null)
            {
               DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where((x, i) => i < EOF)
                   .CopyToDataTable();
            }
```

Comment: I made a slight update to code to make more efficient.

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` can make it so your `int EOF` can be 0. In that case your next `.Where()` statement would return nothing instead of everything. What about `.FirstOrDefault() ?? dt.Rows.Count` to make sure to return all rows if EOF is not found?

Comment: I updated code.  Was just thinking about null case before I read your response.

Comment: It will never return `null`, `default(int)` returns 0 if it's not found.

Comment: I changed it to int? which does return null.  Try : int? a = default(int?);

Comment: `x.Index` is an `int`. `.FirstOrDefault()` will always return an `int`. So just change EOF to be an `int` and check for it not to be 0 instead of null.

Comment: I do not like using int.  The reason is you get the same results if EOF is on the first row and if EOF is not in the file.  For debugging it is better to have 0 when EOR is on the first line and null when EOF doesn't exist.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but `.FirstOrDefault()` will always return an `int` in that case, doesn't matter if EOF is an `int` or `int?`. EOF will never be null even though it's an `int?` because `.FirstOrDefault()` would have returned 0 if not found.